# Is the nullspace of $A$ always a subspace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For instance, when given a system $Ax=b$, the nullspace is the solution space for this nonhomogeneous system. But does this solution space form a subspace of $A$?

Comment: When $b\neq 0$, the nullspace of $A$ contains no solution. But yes, the nullspace of a linear map is a vector subspace.

Comment: What is a subspace of a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused.

In a general setting $A$ is a *linear map* from a *vector space* $X$ to (perhaps another) vector space $Y$ (in notation $A:X\to Y$). Now $x$ lives in $X$ and $b$ lives in $Y$, and the nullspace of $A$ (also known as the *kernel* of $A$) consists of all vectors $x\in X$ such that $Ax=0$ (this latter $0$ lives in $Y$). So, it is a subspace indeed, but of $X$. And it is the solution for the *homogenuous* part of the equation $Ax=b$, i.e. when the constant $b$ is replaced to $0$.

In a more particular setting, $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix (say, with real coefficients), but then we can consider the linear map $\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n,\ \, x\mapsto A\cdot x$.

Comment: thanks for clearing a bunch of things up for me. really got to bunker down for that big Linear Algebra final on monday!